# Как выполнить функцию после нескольких AJAX ( количество ajax неизвестно )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как после получения ответов сервера от всех AJAX, запустить функцию?
Количество AJAX запросов неизвестно, всегда может быть разным.
Но нужно дождаться ответа от них и на основании полученных данных выполнить функцию

```js
function first(i) { 
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: myajax.url,
    data: {
      action:   'testAjax'
    },
    complete: function(response) {
        window.console.log('AJAX');
        if ( i === 5 ) { 
          second(); 
        }
    }
  }); 
};
function second() { window.console.log('Функция после AJAX'); };


for (var i = 1, max = 5; i <= max; i++) {
  first(i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const arr = [];

for (let idx = 1; idx < 6; idx++) {
  arr.push(
    $.ajax({
      url: `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${idx}`,
      type: 'GET'
    })
  );
}

Promise.all(arr)
  .then(values => {
    // обработка результатов
    console.log(values);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // обработка ошибок выполнения запросов
    throw err;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```